# Why doesn't Wordpress plugin 'WP-Syntax' color Java well?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syntax-highlighting

Look at [this post](http://ripper234.com/p/java-is-less-magical-than-c/) for example - the C# examples are highlighted very well, but the Java ones are poor. I'm using the latest version of 
[WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/)

BTW, does this belong on UserVoice or here? I couldn't quite decide.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the CSS and it seems that all styles are inlined. So I think that the Java config of WP-Syntax is using these ugly defaults. If WP-Syntax was using CSS classes for the highlight, it would be simple to fix.